# Why text is not formatted with Html.fromHTML?

Tags: android, html

I'm trying to display html code in text view. I want to display this:

[image: Code]

I'm using this page to generate this code: http://tohtml.com/java/

HTML:

```
<pre style='color:#000000;background:#ffffff;'><span style='color:#7f0055; font-weight:bold; '>public</span> <span style='color:#7f0055; font-weight:bold; '>class</span> MainActivity <span style='color:#7f0055; font-weight:bold; '>extends</span> Activity {


     <span style='color:#3f7f59; '>// Called when activity is created</span>
     @Override
     <span style='color:#7f0055; font-weight:bold; '>protected</span> <span style='color:#7f0055; font-weight:bold; '>void</span> onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
         <span style='color:#7f0055; font-weight:bold; '>super</span>.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
     }
}
</pre>
```

I'm tried this:

```
TextView textView; // my text view
String data = loadDataAsString("/sdcard/code.html"); // my function which loads data from file and returning it as String.
textView.setText(Html.fromHTML(data), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

And i'm getting this as result:

[image: Result]

How can I fix it?

I don't want to use WebView.

I'm using API 19 (Android 4.4.4 - KitKat)

Comment: quick google search said that tags `pre` and `span` are not supported ... also i'm pretty sure that `style` attribute neither

Comment: @Selvin Is there any solution to make this?

Comment: maybe you should use `font` tag

Comment: @Selvin Add this as answer and I will vote up and mark as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Html.fromHtml()` supports only a subset of HTML tags. [This list](https://commonsware.com/blog/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) is a bit out of date, but it will give you the idea of what you can and cannot use. You would need to alter your HTML to abide by the HTML elements that `fromHtml()` can work with.

Alternatively:

- Use a `WebView` instead of a `TextView`, or
- Use a different HTML->`Spanned` parser, like [my `SpannableStringGenerator`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit#usage-xhtml-conversion), if it works with HTML that is more to your liking